# Multiple MySQL JOINs and duplicated cells

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I have two MySQL queries that give the results that I'm looking for. I'd ultimately like to combine these two queries to produce a single table and I'm stuck.

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT scoc.isr, outcome_concept_id, concept_name as outcome_name
FROM standard_case_outcome AS sco INNER JOIN concept AS c
ON sco.outcome_concept_id = c.concept_id
INNER JOIN standard_case_outcome_category AS scoc
ON scoc.isr = sco.isr
WHERE scoc.outc_code = 'CA'
```

RESULT 1:

[image: RESULT OF QUERY 1 (TRUNCATED)]

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT scoc.isr, drug_seq, concept_id, concept_name as drug_name
FROM standard_case_drug AS scd INNER JOIN concept AS c
ON scd.standard_concept_id = c.concept_id
INNER JOIN standard_case_outcome_category AS scoc
ON scoc.isr = scd.isr
WHERE scoc.outc_code = 'CA'
```

RESULT 2:

[image: RESULT OF QUERY 2 (TRUNCATED)]

DESIRED RESULT:
[image: DESIRED RESULT]

I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to do it using Python/pandas, but I was wondering if there is (a) a way to do this MySQL (b) any benefit to doing it with MySQL.

** If you're curious, [this is the entire dataset](http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.8q0s4).

Here's the db structure for the pertinent tables:

```
# Dump of table concept
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `concept` (
  `concept_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `concept_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `domain_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `vocabulary_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `concept_class_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `standard_concept` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `concept_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `valid_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `valid_end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `invalid_reason` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`concept_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_concept_concept_id` (`concept_id`),
  KEY `idx_concept_code` (`concept_code`),
  KEY `idx_concept_vocabluary_id` (`vocabulary_id`),
  KEY `idx_concept_domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `idx_concept_class_id` (`concept_class_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table standard_case_drug
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `standard_case_drug` (
  `primaryid` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isr` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `drug_seq` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_cod` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `standard_concept_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_standard_case_drug_primary_id` (`primaryid`(255),`drug_seq`(255)),
  KEY `idx_standard_case_drug_isr` (`isr`(255),`drug_seq`(255)),
  KEY `idx_standard_case_drug_standard_concept_id` (`standard_concept_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table standard_case_outcome
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `standard_case_outcome` (
  `primaryid` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isr` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pt` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outcome_concept_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `snomed_outcome_concept_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_standard_case_outcome_primary_id` (`primaryid`(255)),
  KEY `idx_standard_case_outcome_isr` (`isr`(255)),
  KEY `idx_standard_case_outcome_outcome_concept_id` (`outcome_concept_id`),
  KEY `idx_standard_case_outcome_snomed_outcome_concept_id` (`snomed_outcome_concept_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table standard_case_outcome_category
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `standard_case_outcome_category` (
  `primaryid` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isr` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outc_code` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Code for a patient outcome (See table below) CODE MEANING_TEXT ----------------DE Death LT Life-ThreateningHO Hospitalization - Initial or ProlongedDS DisabilityCA Congenital AnomalyRI Required Intervention to Prevent PermanentImpairment/DamageOT Other Serious (Important Medical Event) NOTE: The outcome from the latest version of a case is provided. If there is more than one outcome, the codes willbe line listed.',
  `snomed_concept_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_standard_case_outcome_category_primary_id` (`primaryid`(255)),
  KEY `idx_standard_case_outcome_category_isr` (`isr`(255)),
  KEY `idx_standard_case_outcome_category_snomed_concept_id` (`snomed_concept_id`,`outc_code`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  The intermediate queries don't really explain your data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @GordonLinoff. The dataset is almost 1GB so I'll have to think about the best way to get a small segment that will still provide results.  As for the structure, I'll make that update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the desired results.

```
SELECT
    `scoc`.`isr`                AS `isr`,
    `sco` .`outcome_concept_id` AS `outcome_concept_id`,
    `c1`  .`concept_name`       AS `outcome_name`,
    `scd` .`drug_seq`           AS `drug_seq`,
    `scd` .`concept_id`         AS `concept_id`,
    `c2`  .`concept_name`       AS `drug_name`
FROM
    `standard_case_outcome` AS `sco`
INNER JOIN
    `concept` AS `c1`
    ON
        `sco`.`outcome_concept_id` = `c1`.`concept_id`
LEFT JOIN
    `standard_case_drug` AS `scd`
    ON
        `sco`.`isr` = `scd`.`isr`
INNER JOIN
    `concept` AS `c2`
    ON
        `scd`.`outcome_concept_id` = `c2`.`concept_id`
INNER JOIN
    `standard_case_outcome_category` AS `scoc`
    ON
        `scoc`.`isr` = `sco`.`isr`
WHERE
    `scoc`.`outc_code` = 'CA'
```

**EDIT**

Note that I left out the `concept` table, as you are not selecting anything from it, or filtering the results with it.

**SECOND EDIT**

Updated to include the `concept` table. Updated question showed that it is in fact needed in the `SELECT`.

**THIRD EDIT**

Needs to select `concept`.`name` for `sco`, and `scd` respectively.

Comment: Thank you @ÞóiJuhasz. That was incredibly fast.  concept_name does, in fact, come from the concept table though.

Comment: That's where your update to the post came in handy. Sorry for the assumption, I'll update the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: This appears to be very close after the second edit. The line `scd` .`concept_name` AS `drug_name` gives an error because concept name is not in the `scd` table. It's in the `c` table.  Because the outcome_name and the drug_name both come from the concepts table, as determined by the concept_id, it doesn't allow for a simple change to `c` .`concept_name` AS `drug_name`

Comment: Why would you need the same column to be selected twice anyway?

Comment: Ah, sorry for being hasty, I think I got your meaning. Have a look at the third edit.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks a ton. This is very fast too. There are about 15.5 million rows in the dataset and this runs in 13.0ms.  I really appreciate your help.